# Is there a quick way of toggling the predictive keyboard on iOS 13?

Tags: ios

On previous versions of iOS, I’ve generally kept the predictive keyboard turned completely off, since I found it very distracting when trying to type.

However, with iOS 13’s new swipe-to-type functionality, I find the predictive keyboard is very necessary in order to correct mispredicted words while swiping. I’d like to be able to quickly turn the predictive keyboard on and off so that I can use it when I feel like swiping but keep it hidden most of the time.

In previous versions of iOS, there were at least two ways to quickly toggle the predictive keyboard:

1. Swiping down on the predictive keyboard would collapse it into a smaller form and hide its predictions, and swiping up would restore it.
2. When pressing and holding the globe button on the keyboard, there was a toggle switch there that would turn the predictive keyboard off entirely.

Now, however, the toggle switch is not present, replaced with a “keyboard settings” option that sends me out to the settings app where I have to hunt for the option, and swiping down on the predictive keyboard appears to do nothing.

Are these options just gone forever, or is “Keyboard Settings…”—>”Predictive” really the fastest way of toggling the visibility of the predictive keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is currently the only way to turn off the predictive keyboard. As of not, no shortcut exists to do it in the Shortcuts app either.

This is also the only way mentioned by [this Apple article](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iphd4ea90231/13.0/ios/13.0).